# After upgrading to expo v48 and removing @types/react-native (because react-native 0.71 contains this), I can't start the app unless I add it again

Tags: typescript, react-native, sdk, frontend, expo

I am having trouble building a program written in react-native using expo. After upgrading to expo v48 (from v47) and therefore react-native 0.78.1, in the documentation it says that you should remove the @types/react-native dependency as it is included with react-native 0.71 and onwards, but after I remove it from my project and build the app using npx expo start It complains that I don't have that dependency installed, and I can't run the app unless I install it. There's no place from where it can use another version of react-native that doesn't have these types included, and I also used the react native upgrade helper to make sure I have every other thing that's needed configured properly. I want to solve this, without having to add @types/react-native in package.json (since, at least theoretically, it should not be necessary).

Has anyone else encountered this issue or does anyone know how to solve it?

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2O3X.png)

- Running on a different system
- Deleting node_modules and running yarn install again
- Installing what I saw different in react native upgrade helper

Comment: Apparently setting the environment variable EXPO_NO_TYPESCRIPT_SETUP to true solved this problem.